# Comunicación de componentes en REACT

Tags: reactjs

Estoy realizando un CRUD en react de contactos. Pero tengo un problema al querer actualizar un contacto.

Tengo un componente formulario que guarda en un json información de contactos. Unas tarjetas en un componente padre son llenadas con este json. En cada una de las tarjetas creadas en el componente padre hay un botón de actualizar, que, la idea es que me devuelva esa información al formulario (hijo) para editar.

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo realizar esto sin usar redux?

Este es el componente principal:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

// data
import { todos } from './todos.json';

// subcomponents
import TodoForm from './components/TodoForm';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos
    }
    this.handleAddTodo = this.handleAddTodo.bind(this);
  }

  removeTodo(index) {
    this.state.todos.splice(index, 1);  ///Elimino el objeto del arreglo de ToDos
    this.setState({
      ToDos: this.state.ToDos //Refresco la información para que React lo detecte y aplique el renderizado
    });
  }

  actualizarTodo(index){
    var elemento = this.state.todos[index];
    console.log(elemento.title);
    <TodoForm onAddTodo={this.handleAddTodo}></TodoForm>

  }

  handleAddTodo(todo) {
    this.setState({
      todos: [...this.state.todos, todo]
    })
  }

  render() {
    const todos = this.state.todos.map((todo, i) => {
      return (
        <div className="col-md-4" key={i}>
          <div className="card mt-4">
            <div className="card-title text-center">
              <h3>{todo.nombre}</h3>
              <span className="badge badge-warning">
                {todo.codigo}
              </span>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
              {todo.numero1}
            </div>
            <div className="card-footer">
              <button
                className="btn btn-info"
                onClick={this.removeTodo.bind(this, i)}>
                Eliminar
              </button>
              <button
                className="btn btn-info"
                onClick={this.actualizarTodo.bind(this, i)}>
                Actualizar
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    });

    return (
      <div className="App">

        <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <span className="badge badge-pill badge-light ml-2">
                C R U D S 
            </span>
          </a>
        </nav>

        <div className="container">
          <div className="row mt-4">

            <div className="col-md-4 text-center">

              <TodoForm onAddTodo={this.handleAddTodo} id="frm"></TodoForm>
            </div>

            <div className="col-md-8">
              <div className="row">
                {todos}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Este el componente formulario:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TodoForm extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      nombre: '',
      numero1: '',
      numero2: '',
      codigo: '+57'
    };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onAddTodo(this.state);
    this.setState({
      nombre: '',
      numero1: '',
      numero2: '',
      codigo: '+57'
    });
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    const {value, name} = e.target;
    console.log(value, name);
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="card-body">
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="nombre"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.title}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Nombre"
              />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <select
                name="codigo"
                className="form-control"
                value={this.state.priority}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              >
              <option>+57</option>
              <option>+58</option>
              <option>+56</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="numero1"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.responsible}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Número 1"
              />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="numero2"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.description}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Número 2"
              />
          </div>

          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Guardar
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default TodoForm;
```

De pronto ayude a entender más la idea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A ver si entiendo, quieres que cuando apreten actualizar, la información de la tarjeta, se ponga en el formulario del padre?

Comment: Exactamente es la idea